# Is this invasive plant, with medium green-colored leaves and serrated edges, a Sweet Joe Pye Weed?

Tags: identification

I'm trying to identify if this is a Sweet Joe Pye Weed

[image]

Comment: Looks like a Hydrangea to me...

Comment: @LS Menzies I would expect the stem to be red on the portion of the plant where the leaves meet the stem if it were Sweet Joe.

Comment: a.k.a. Hortensia, likes (half)shade

Comment: Welcome! If you have a moment, I suggest you take the [tour] and browse our [help] to learn more about the site. For identification questions, the [tag info](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/tags/identification/info) gives a few pointers, how you can [edit] and improve the question and  get better answers. If you have questions, feel free to ask.

Comment: It turns out that my gf always knew it was a hydrangea. Seems there was some miscommunication that sent me off on my errant mission. Thanks for all the feedback.

Answer (score 1):

Two characteristics of Joe Pye Weed (Eupatorium purpureum) are: leaves usually in whorls of 3 or greater, and the leaves smell of vanilla when bruised (Hortus Third, 1976). Clearly this plant has opposite leaves in twos so this says it is likely not Joe Pye weed. I'll leave the bruising test to you.